# Errors Installiing USB Coral

Tags: python, key

Trying to install the runtime.  When I run the line with the Curl command:

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

I get the following error indicating that the apt-key is deprecated:

> Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8))

Then, when I run the command to install Python, I get the following:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-pycoral : Depends: python3-tflite-runtime (= 2.5.0.post1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3 (< 3.10) but 3.10.6-1~22.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I don't know if the problems are related.

Need help!

TIA

Joe

I tried to look at the keys, but my knowledge is limited.

Answer (score 0):

The key is not the issue. While apt-key *is* depreciated, most tutorials online still have the apt-key command in their steps. Use [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1307181) link in order to get an answer that improves the security and gets around the warning in your installation.

Your issue appears to be that the package `python3-tflite-runtime` needs a version of python under 3.10 `Depends: python3 (< 3.10)`. This can be achived by uninstalling your current version of python (3.10.6-1~22.04) and installing version 3.9 or lower.

The commands you may need to solve this:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt remove python3
sudo apt install python3.9
```